# How to delete temp_file?

Tags: r, temp

I am noob in R-programming. I have started a course on EdX for R and was following the chain o codes explained in the video. I got stock where in video the said to delete the temp file using the function of `file.remove` ? I followed in my Rstudio but got the following error `Warning message: In file.remove(tmp_ali) : cannot remove file 'C:\Users\Sbp\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpyqN59T\file38fc3b51325f', reason 'Permission denied'`

Please note that my windows10 is not activated. Idk if the problem is due to this or is there any thing that I can do to fix his problem

Comment: Why do you need to remove the temporary file? Also, confirm that the file actually exists before attempting to remove it.

Comment: how to confirm?

Comment: Use `file.exists` to check it